# How do I access mongos db.system.js in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I can access it fine using meteor mongo but I need access to it on the server...
How do I do that?

I've tried:

```
Meteor.system.js.save()
db.system.js.save()
System.js.save()
```

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Not sure why its relevant but I added what I tried in my server folder.

Comment: I don't think meteor supports that natively, but you can probably find an npm package that you can use for that, or wrap into a new meteor package if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it through the node mongo driver directly [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884223/728291).  So for the `system.js` collection I think you use:

```
// on server
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver.mongo.db;
var systemJS = db.collection('system.js');
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10211076/728291) shows some non-meteor examples of code for the node driver.